# Morris.js no me muestra correctamente el eje X

Tags: javascript

Tengo una gráfica como la siguiente:

[image: gráfica]

los datos de la gráfica los cojo de esta [URL](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?aggregate=1&fsym=BTC&tsym=EUR&limit=30&extraParams=CryptoAssistant)

y mi función javascript es la siguiente:

```
function charts(){
    {% for coin in UserCoins %}
      $.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?aggregate=1&fsym={{coin.short_name}}&tsym=EUR&limit=30&extraParams=CryptoAssistant",function(data){
          //charts
          new Morris.Line({
            element: 'chart_{{coin.name}}',
            data: data['Data'],
            xkey: ['time'],
            ykeys: ['close'],
            labels: ['Close'],
            hideHover: 'auto',
            lineColors: ['#F96332'],
            pointSize: 0,
            postUnits: "€",
            xLabelFormat: function (timestamp) {
                          var date = new Date(timestamp);
                          return date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                        }
          });
      });
    {% endfor %}
  }
```

Me gustaría conseguir que se mostrase en el eje de las X los días del mes, puesto que el json tiene una entrada para cada día del mes, sin embargo, no se muestra nada...

He probado jugando con las propiedades **xLabelFormat**, **xLabels** y nada.
También he probado a agrandar la gráfica y aunque se muestran más labels en el eje x, ni de lejos se muestra el día a día.

Actualmente me muestra fechas de 1970, cuando el timestamp recibido por parte del json es correcto y tampoco se el motivo.

¿Alguien puede aportarme alguna pista sobre dónde tengo el fallo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He modificado mi función para formatear el timestampt que obtengo del get por la fehca formateada:

```
function charts(){
        {% for coin in UserCoins %}
          $.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?aggregate=1&fsym={{coin.short_name}}&tsym=EUR&limit=30&extraParams=CryptoAssistant",function(data){
              all_data = []
              for (var act in data['Data']){
                data_ = new Object();
                data_['time'] = new Date(data['Data'][act]["time"]*1000).toLocaleDateString();
                data_['close'] = data['Data'][act]['close'];
                all_data.push(data_);
              }
              //charts
              new Morris.Line({
                element: 'chart_{{coin.name}}',
                data: all_data,
                xkey: 'time',
                ykeys: ['close'],
                labels: ['Close'],
                hideHover: 'auto',
                lineColors: ['#F96332'],
                pointSize: 0,
                postUnits: "€",
                parseTime: false
              });
          });
        {% endfor %}
      }
```